# Set keyboard shortcut for a JButton?

Tags: java, swing, keyboard-shortcuts, action, jbutton

I have a type game in which you have to type the words that appear as fast as possible before the time limit runs out, but every time you type a word, you must move the mouse and click enter and click back into the user input to type the next word.  I was just hoping if there was way to use "keyCode.VK_Enter" to issue an Action Command called by the JButton.

Some snippets of my code:

The Enter button and user input and output:

```
enter = new JButton("Enter");
    enter.setFont(serif);  //serif is specified earlier
    enter.setActionCommand("Enter");
    enter.addActionListener(this);
    container.add(enter);

userOutput = new JTextField(50);
    userOutput.setFont(serif);
    container.add(userOutput);
    userOutput.setEditable(false);

userInput = new JTextField(43);
    userInput.setFont(serif);
    container.add(userInput);
    userInput.setEditable(false);
```

The actionPerformed method getting the enter button's action command:

```
if(userInput.getText().equals(userOutput.getText())){
            userInput.setText("");
            score += 100;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why don't you just add an actionlistener to the JTextField (which would be triggered when the user hits enter).

```
userInput.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        // Do something
    }

});
```

Comment: +1, Yes, the ActionListener can be shared by both the button and the text field.

Comment: Wow!  Thanks a lot, I didn't know the ActionCommands could be shared lol.  Thanks!

Comment: @AmundeepSingh, then maybe you should be accepting the answer?